# how to convert int to index path in tableview cell?

Tags: swift

I have to change the height of the last row of the table view.so I am taking my array count value for index path.

```
var myArray = NSArray()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        if indexPath.row == myArray.count
        {
            return 400
        }
        return 120
    }
```

but height is not changing. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Change `if-condition` to `if indexPath.row == (myArray.count - 1)`

Comment: > usage of `NSArray`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `NSArray` in Swift. Use its strongly-typed native Swift equivalent, `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `if indexPath.row == myArray.count`  will never hit

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == myArray.count {
        return 400
    } 
    return 120
}
```

As when dataSource count is `myArray.count` , then `indexPath.row` will be from 0 up to `myArray.count` , if you need to change the height of the last row do

```
if indexPath.row == myArray.count - 1 {
```

Or shortly

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
   return ( indexPath.row == myArray.count - 1 ) ? 400 : 120 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
array counter will start from 1 but your tableView row will start from 0
So `if indexPath.row == myArray.count` will never hit

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == myArray.count - 1 {
        return 400
    } 
    return 120
}
```

Comment: To make your answer useful for both OP and future readers, you should be providing a proper explanation of what your code does, not just "try this".